# How to put different symbols in autoplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm having some troubles with `autoplot()` in survival objects. I will take the below as example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)
library(survival)
    datalung <- lung
    fitlung<- survfit(Surv(time,status) ~ sex,type = "kaplan-meier",data=datalung)
    autoplot(fitlung,conf.int=FALSE,pVal=TRUE,pX=800)+scale_color_grey()
```

[image]

In the example above, sex 1 and 2 have different grey scales, with just 2 groups it's fine to see the different groups.

The real dataset that I'm using have 9 different groups, and is hard to see the differents curves with this grey scale. I can't use colours. What I'm looking for is a way to put symbols to different groups, but I can't find this parameter in `autoplot`.

The `surv.linetype` have the option `solid` and `dashed`, but it changes all curves with same pattern and I don't want it. Taking the `lung` data as example, I want to put different `linetype` for sex 1 and sex 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking through the function code usually helps me figure out what can and cannot be changed.  You can look at the code for `autoplot.survfit` by running `ggfortify:::autoplot.survfit` in the Console.

Looking through that you'll see only the `color` aesthetic is used for groupings.  I didn't see an easy way to change this, but you can easily follow the recipe in the function to make your own plot.  While building your own plot takes a few more steps, it gives you a lot of flexibility.

For example, if you wanted to change the shape of the lines and points for each group you can `fortify` the model and then build the plot.

```
plot.data = fortify(fitlung, surv.connect = TRUE)

ggplot(plot.data, aes(time, surv, shape = strata)) +
    geom_step(aes(linetype = strata)) +
    geom_point(data = subset(plot.data, n.censor > 0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Note that I only know of 6 line types; even if there were more they would be difficult to tell apart.  Shapes aren't much better, although there are more of those.

Comment: What I can do when I have more than 6 discrete values. The shape palette can deal with a maximum of 6 discrete values because more
than 6 becomes difficult to discriminate; you have 9. Consider specifying
shapes manually if you must have them.

Comment: @Roland When you have more than 6 values you have to use `scale_shape_manual` to pick more values yourself.  For example, `scale_shape_manual(values = 1:9)` is a simple version, although you'd probably want to pick shapes more carefully than this.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @aosmith's answer, you can keep some of the features of `ggfortify::autoplot()` by suppressing its `surv.linetype` and adding your lines manually. Although, you have to explicitly specify the labels or else each 'geom' gets its own set of labels.

```
autoplot(fitlung, surv.linetype = 'blank',
                      conf.int=FALSE, pVal=TRUE, pX=800) +
geom_step(aes(linetype=strata) ) +
scale_linetype_manual(values = c('solid', 'dotted'), 
    labels = c('sex1', 'sex2') ) +
scale_color_manual(values = c('black', 'black'), 
     labels = c('sex1', 'sex2') )
```