# ggsurv legends and line thickness

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some problems with the ggsurv function in ggplot.

I want to control the order of appearance with legends and the line style.

I can see that others have similar problems but I dont understand the solution

Using the standard lung data my problem is as

```
library(GGally)
library(survival)
data(lung)
surv1 <- survfit(Surv(time,status) ~ sex, data = lung)
p1 <- ggsurv(surv1, lty.est=c(1,2), surv.col=c("black", "red" ))
p1 <- p1 + scale_colour_discrete(name = 'sex', breaks = c(1,2), labels=c('XX','XY'))
p1
```

Here I would have expected the standard values in the legend replaced with XX and XY. But I get a duplicated legend instead. One with correct line attributes but wrong names and color. Another with correct names and color but wrong line attributes.

I have tried to insert

```
p1 <- p1 + guides(colour = FALSE)
```

but that removes the wrong part of the legend

What do I not understand?

Thanks to cuttlefish's comments a solution is:

```
library(GGally)
library(survival)
data(lung)
surv1 <- survfit(Surv(time,status) ~ sex, data = lung)
p1 <- ggsurv(surv1, lty.est=c(1,2), surv.col=c("black", "red" ))
p1 <- p1  + scale_colour_discrete(name = 'sex', breaks = c(1,2), labels=c('XX','XY'))
p1 <- p1 + guides(linetype = F, colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(2,1)))) 
p1
```

I can understand that the override.aes manually set the line types used in the legend. I am not fully sure what the linetype = F actually does, but it works!

A second question. How do You manually set the thickness of the lines (both in the graph and the legend)

Adding

```
p1 <- p1 + geom_line(size=2)
```

does not work. It draws ugly black lines which not are fully aligned with the orignal ones.

Comment: Thanks it soluted my first problem. Added it above. It rises a new problem how I change line thickness

Comment: The lines are drawn using `geom_step`, not `geom_line`.  So `geom_step(size = 2)` would do what you want although you might not be able to control the colors.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907004/how-to-put-different-symbols-in-autoplot/39908638#39908638) shows what the ggplot2 code looks like if you were building this graph "by hand" after using `ggfortify::fortify` on the model.

Comment: aosmith geom_step is the right one. Now I have the correct lines. But they are Black and not as specified in surv.col black and red. I did not notice it before but the solution above actually was red and green and not red and black. Strangely enough (at least for me) with the geom_step line inserted the legend colrs continued to be red green, although the lines is thick black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally due to the advice of aosmith, it worked with ggfortify (which I didnt know)

For others in the same situation here is my code where I by hand could change what I wanted

```
if(!require(survival)){
  install.packages("survival")
}
library(survival)

if(!require(GGally)){
  install.packages("GGally")
}
library(GGally)

if(!require(ggplot2)){
  install.packages("ggplot2")
}
library(ggplot2)

if(!require(ggfortify)){
  install.packages("ggfortify")
}
library(ggfortify)


    fit <- survfit(Surv(age_at_ecg, age_at_censor, dod) ~ rs9388451, data = exom)
    plot.data = fortify(fit)
    p1 <- ggplot(plot.data, aes(time, surv, color = strata))
    p1 <- p1 + geom_point(size=0) 
    p1 <- p1 + geom_step(size=2)
    p1 <- p1 + scale_color_manual(name = "rs9388451", labels = c('WT', 'Heterozygote', 'Homozygote'), values = c('black', 'blue', 'red'))
    p1 <- p1 + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(30,80),breaks=seq(30,80,10)) # x ticks from 0 to 180 by 30
    p1 <- p1 + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.80,1),breaks=seq(0.80,1,0.05))
    p1 <- p1 + xlab("Age (years)")
    p1 <- p1 + ylab('Survival')
    p1 <- p1 + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="white")) # white plot background
    p1 <- p1 + theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill="white"))
    p1 <- p1 + theme(axis.title.y=element_text(margin=margin(0,15,0,0))) # Add space to axis title
    p1 <- p1 + 
      theme(axis.text=element_text(size=25,face="bold",colour="black"), axis.title=element_text(size=25,face="bold"))
    p1 <- p1 + theme(legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size=15, face="bold"))
    p1 <- p1 + theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=15, face="bold"))
    p1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine legends by using both `scale_color` and `scale_linetype`, making sure the two scales have the same name and labels.  Looks like the colors need to be defined again in `scale_color_manual`.

You can add the lines via `geom_step`, setting the correct colors and line types by using the variable `group` present from the `ggsurv` object.  The downside of this is that a second set of lines is drawn on top of the original so the result doesn't necessarily look particularly nice.

```
ggsurv(surv1, lty.est=c(1,2), surv.col=c("black", "red" )) +
    scale_color_manual(name = "sex", values = c("black", "red"), labels = c("XX", "YY")) +
    scale_linetype_discrete(name = "sex", labels = c("XX", "YY")) +
    geom_step(size = 1, aes(color = group, linetype = group))
```

There's a point when you want to change enough things that it is worth building the graph "by hand" with ggplot2.  This can be done for survival models by using `fortify` from *ggfortify* on the model object.

```
library(ggfortify)      
library(ggplot2)        
plot.data = fortify(surv1, surv.connect = TRUE)

ggplot(plot.data, aes(time, surv, color = strata)) +
    geom_step(aes(linetype = strata), size = 1) +
    geom_point(data = subset(plot.data, n.censor > 0), shape = 3, color = "red") +
    scale_color_manual(name = "sex", labels = c("XX", "YY"), values = c("black", "red")) +
    scale_linetype_discrete(name = "sex", labels = c("XX", "YY")) +
    labs(y = "Survival", x = "Time")
```